# looping trouble in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, permutation, random

Suppose a matrix is given say d.

```
d=[1.32 4.354 6.78 4.56; 
   4.65 3.23  2.34 8.9; 
   2.32 7.65  4.98 2.78]
```

I require to pick values such that no two values chosen are same. Say I want to pick 5 values in an increment of 1 using Matlab.

```
for ii=1:5
  % pick value one by one such that no two values chosen are same
end
```

loop should function like this:

```
  ii=1, d'=4.354
  ii=2, d'=4.354 2.32
```

It shouldn't be :

```
   ii=2, d'=4.354 4.354
```

Comment: It would possible help if you explained *how* you are selecting values from `d`. Do you want to systematically work through `d`? I.e. `i=1, d'=1.32; i=2,d'=1.32,4.354, etc`

Comment: Vectorize, do not loop. Will provide solution when not on phone.

Comment: i don't require systematically selection, it could be random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [randperm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) to create a [linear index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) of 5 random non-repeating numbers:

```
d(randperm(numel(d),5))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pick unique values for `d`, simply use `unique` to remove replicates before picking:

```
 ud = unique( d(:) ); % note the (:) - we want element-wise unique and not row-unique

 ud(1:5) % picks first fiver unique elements
```